# Is there a good/best way to extend a nested class in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, cocoa-design-patterns

Sometimes framework objects put helper class interfaces inside of *.m files, such as:

Foo.m:

```
@interface HelperObject : NSObject
/*...*/
@end
@implementation HelperObject
/*...*/
@end

@implementation Foo
/*...*/
@end
```

If I want to extend Foo, for instance using a category, is there a way to extend HelperObject as well? More generally, is doing so a violation of encapsulation? Should I try to extend the class functionality without extending HelperObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callers of `Foo` know *nothing* about `HelperObject`--frequently, they do not even know it exists. So no, it's not safe or valid to be subclassing it in another file.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend either Helper or Foo using categories, but you can't extend both with a single category.  Given the relationship between Helper and Foo (where Helper is effectively an invisible helper class), I don't see much value in allowing that.

In general, Objective-C does not support multiple inheritance of either classes or categories.

It does, however, support multiple inheritance of interfaces through protocols.

That is, you could declare a protocol in your `.m` file that both Helper and Foo implement.

Answer (score 0):

Objective C doesn't allow nested classes (unlike Java or C++ for example).
You can use aggregation to expand classes functionality. If you want to hide something you can use Pimpl idiom, however it is not necessary in ObjC cause you can easily replace that with category.

Edit: if you want to extend HelperObject object using category you should declare it in the same file where you want to use that functions (so they are visible).